# How to define two variable x=20, y=5 and then to print division of x and y (i.e. x/y) bash script

Tags: bash

I tried this but i am getting error:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/Documents$ x=20
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/Documents$ y=5
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/Documents$ expr x / y
expr: non-integer argument
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/33062619/7552

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `$` in front of a variable name to refer to its contents.

```
pilot6@Pilot6:~$ x=20
pilot6@Pilot6:~$ y=5
pilot6@Pilot6:~$ expr $x / $y
4
```